# Inserting a letter/number sequence to multiple child span tags using .text(). Is there a more efficient way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use specific letters of the alphabet to insert into a number of span tags, maybe 20 lets say. Do I need 20 lines of .text() or is there a more efficient way? Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".owl-page:first-child span").text("A");
    $(".owl-page:nth-child(2) span").text("C");
    $(".owl-page:nth-child(3) span").text("D");
    $(".owl-page:nth-child(4) span").text("E");
    $(".owl-page:nth-child(5) span").text("F");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the other answers but slightly different approach:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bk8ev056/5/)

```
var letters = {
    1: 'A',
    2: 'B',
    3: 'C',
    4: 'D',
    5: 'E',
    6: 'F'
}

$.each(letters, function(e) {
  $('.owl-page:nth-child(' + e + ') span').text(this);
});
```

Comment: And `$(this)[0]` is more simply written as `this`.

Comment: Actually, `$(this)[0]` probably won't work at all. `this` will be a string like `C`, so `$(this)` is a selector for a `<c>` element. Since this won't find anything, `$(this)[0]` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Did you check the fiddle? It all works. But yeah `this` will work instead. But it doesn't need + 1 because e is not referring to its index.

Comment: It's weird. `this` is a boxed string object, and for some reason jQuery knows not to treat it as a selector.

Comment: Testing these out. So far this is the only one I can get to work. Just a note - there is no letter "B" and have to add the span in there. `$('.owl-page:nth-child(' + e + ') span').text(this);` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the letters in an array and use them with .each() method.

```
var letters = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
var counter = 0;

$(".owl-page > * span").each(function(){ 
    if(counter >= letters.length) 
        return false; 
    $(this).text(letters[counter]);
    counter++;
});
```

Comment: I originally used that selector in my answer, but I changed it. What if there's more than one span in each child?